# Double click then pressing control+shift shows a number 1 on a blue background

Tags: firefox

Recently a new, odd behavior showed up in Firefox.  If I double click the mouse, then press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> a number `1` on a blue background shows up under the mouse pointer. Visible in the left margin in this screenshot:

[image: number]

If I immediately release <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> the number disappears, but if I don't and press <kbd>tab</kbd> (cycle to previous browser tab) the number becomes persistent--it's still there when I return to the tab where it appeared--until I click on the number.

Any idea what's causing this, and how to get rid of it?

Firefox version: 45.0.2

Comment: Can you post what version of FF you're using as well as the extensions you have installed?

Comment: 45.0.2 -- Question updated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a fairly clean FF 45.0.2 install on Win7 Enterprise 32-bit.  Try disabling all your extensions, then re-enabling them one-by-one until you find the offender.

Comment: Yeah, I've been in the process of doing that. I have about 30 installed so it's a pain, but it looks like it's definitely one of the addons. When I figure out which one I'll see if the behavior can be changed or disabled, and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I disabled addons and enabled them until I found which one was causing this behavior.  Turns out it was [Multiple-Highlighter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multiple-highlighter/), and it is behavior that was introduced in the latest update.

If you highlight anything with the mouse and press <kbd>shift</kbd> this number appears and you can click on it to highlight all occurrences of the text the user highlighted.

My solution was to change the setting controlling this behavior from <kbd>shift</kbd> to <kbd>z</kbd>.